# I need JSON key names for each of the transaction types

Tags: yodlee

Are there full samples (XSD equivalent) of the JSON data model available?  Specifically, I need to know the key names for each of the transaction and account types.  The data model located at http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/ shows readable names such as "Transaction Status", but the response payload from v1.0/jsonsdk/TransactionSearchService/executeUserSearchRequest shows the JSON element like this:

"status": {
        "statusId": 1,
        "description": "posted",
        "localizedDescription": "posted"
    }

Please point me to the documentation which shows the XSD equivalent to the JSON objects for each of the transaction types.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

"status": { "statusId": 1, "description": "posted", "localizedDescription": "posted" }

"posted" which is the description here represent the Transaction status.

similarly for pending transaction this will be

"status": { "statusId": 2, "description": "pending", "localizedDescription": "pending" }

So if you want to know about the description which the various transaction base types can have,please visit - 
https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Yodlee_Constants#Transaction_Base_Type

if you want to know about the description which the various transaction types can have please visit - 
https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Yodlee_Constants#Transaction_Type

Transaction types are mostly populated in case of Investments but in case of Banking(savings and checkings)accounts and Credit card accounts you should be looking for transaction base types.

Ex - 
"transactionBaseType":"credit",
    "transactionBaseTypeId":1,